# How does the "Function" constructor work in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I came across two javascript functions, *f1* and *f2*:

```
const expression = "model.test ==0";
const x = ["model"].concat(`return ${expression};`);
const f1 = Function.apply(Function, x);
const f2 = Function.bind.apply(Function,x)();
```

I figure out `f1({ test: 1 })`, it will return *false* while `f1({ test: 0 })` will return *true*.

I don't know how to call *f2* at all. The two keywords `Function` inside each function definition confuses me completely.

Can someone explain what is happening here?

The original function is ad following

```
export function evalStringExpression(expression: string, argNames: string[]) 
{
  try {
    return Function.bind.apply(Function, [void 
      0].concat(argNames.concat(`return ${expression};`)))();
   } catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  }
}
```

// to call :

```
hideExpression = evalStringExpression(hideExpression, ['model', 'formState']);
        }

f_hideExpression = (model, formState) =>  hideExpression(model, formState);
```

I don't know  f_hideExpression is value or function or object.

The code is from https://github.com/formly-js/ngx-formly/search?q=evalStringExpression&unscoped_q=evalStringExpression

it creates a function based on expression input. 
It works pretty magically, I am trying to figurate out how.

Comment: For future reference ... MDN has great documentation, even Microsoft and Google(Chrome) think so ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Comment: The `Function` as 1st argument for `apply` simply sets `this`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: @JaromandaX, thanks, that give me some clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f2` makes no sense whatsoever.

```
const f2 = Function.bind.apply(Function,x)();
```

is

```
const f2 = Function.bind(...x)();
```

is

```
const f2 = Function.call(...x);
```

is

```
const f2 = Function.call("model", 'return "model.test ==0";');
```

but [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) ignores its `this` value so this is the same as

```
const f2 = Function('return "model.test ==0";');
```

which has no parameters and creates a closure over the *global* `model` variable.

Comment: I think the const f2 = Function('model', 'return "model.test ==0";')();   it allows to call f2(model) instead of limited to global model.  Thanks!